# ASP.NET connection strings and DSN connections

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection

I have a dBase file that I want to set up as a database. I was thinking of setting up an ODBC DSN system connection and connect using this. How do I set this up in an asp.net web.config file and use it

```
<connectionStrings configSource="MyFolder\database.config" />
```

Inside Database file

```
<connectionStrings> My Connection Here???</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use OleDb to connect to FoxPro data, but you might connect using ODBC this way:

```
string connectionString = "DSN=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myDSN"];
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

//do something
```

In your web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myDSN" value="DSN Name"/>
</appSettings>
```

I've tested this and it works